# Line integral along curve

Tags: real-analysis, curves, vector-fields, line-integrals

> Let be $h:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function,
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a vector field where $f(x):=h(x)x$,
>
> $C$ a continuously differentiable curve with $C\subset\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \Vert x\Vert_2=R\}$, where $R>0$.
>
> Show that the line integral of the vector field $f$ along $C$ satisfies
> $$
> \int_C f(x)\cdot dx = 0.
> $$

**My approach:**

Let be $\varphi:[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a parametrization of $C$ then we use the definition of the line integral and get
$$
\int_C f(x)\cdot dx= \int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\varphi(t))\cdot \varphi'(t)dt=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}h(\varphi(t))\varphi(t)\cdot \varphi'(t)dt=\int\limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}h(\varphi(t))\left(\varphi_1(t) \varphi_1'(t)+\varphi_2(t) \varphi_2'(t)+\cdots+\varphi_n(t) \varphi_n'(t)\right)dt.
$$
But this doesn't help a lot.

If I take for example $\varphi(t)=\begin{pmatrix}R\cos(t)\\R\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}$ then $\varphi(t)\cdot \varphi'(t)$ vanishes and $\int_C f(x)\cdot dx = 0$. But why is that so? Do you have any hints which way to go?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, im$(\varphi)\subseteq C$ and so $\|\varphi(t)\|^2=R^2$ for all $t$. Then $\langle \varphi(t),\varphi(t)\rangle=R^2$, which implies $\langle\varphi(t),\varphi'(t)\rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the curve is contained in the sphere, the squared length $||\varphi(t)||^2 = \varphi(t)\cdot \varphi(t)$  is constantly equal to $R^2$. Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives $2\varphi(t)\cdot\dot{\varphi}(t) = 0$.